# dicord py using an argument

Tags: discord.py

i am making an embed and trying to use the argument user has to pass in, the number has to be in range(1,13) 1 - 12, can't check if it is range, it's like return only False

```
@client.command()
async def video(ctx, number):
if number == range(1,13):
    await ctx.send('ready')     
else:
    await ctx.send(f'There are only {len(videos)} video(s) on the youtube channel')
```

Don't worry about videos variable, it just has to check if passed in number in the range.
Than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `number` argument is a string you can define at as an int as shown below.

Also you should compare using `in` becasue you can't equate a number to a range.

Here is the code fixed.

```py
@client.command()
async def video(ctx, number: int):
if number in range(1,13):
    await ctx.send('ready')     
else:
    await ctx.send(f'There are only {len(videos)} video(s) on the youtube channel')
```